# PHPExcel attempting to read Excel file using ajax() call is failing

Tags: ajax, phpexcel

I am attempting to read an Excel File using PHPExcel Lib through an ajax call. However, the read attempt is causing an error of `PHPExcel_Reader_Exception: Could not open for reading! File does not exist.`

My index.php is as follows:-

```
<?php
    ob_start();
    ini_set("xdebug.var_display_max_children", -1);
    ini_set("xdebug.var_display_max_data", -1);
    ini_set("xdebug.var_display_max_depth", -1);    
    session_start();

    if ( isset($_POST['label']) ) {
    var_dump($_POST['label']);
    }

?>  


<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script>
    var label;
    function checkfile(sender) {    
      var validExts = new Array(".xlsx", ".xls");   
      var fileExt = sender; 
      fileExt = fileExt.substring(fileExt.lastIndexOf('.'));    
      if (validExts.indexOf(fileExt) < 0) { 
        alert("Invalid file selected, valid files are of " +    
          validExts.toString() + " types.");    
        return false;   
      } else return true;   
    }   

    $(function() {  
          $(document).on('change', ':file', function() {    
            var input = $(this),    
                numFiles = input.get(0).files ? input.get(0).files.length : 1,  
                label = input.val().replace(/\\/g, '/').replace(/.*\//, '');    

            input.trigger('fileselect', [numFiles, label]); 

        }); 
        $(document).ready( function() {     
          $(':file').on('fileselect', function(event, numFiles, label) {        

                if(checkfile(label)== true){         
                    var input = $(this).parents('.input-group').find(':text'),          
                      log = label;              
                    if(input.length) {            
                      input.val(log);               
                    } else {              
                     // if(log) alert(log);             
                    }
                }       
                 $.ajax({  
                    //url:"../uploadxlsx/readxlsx.php",     
                    url:"uploadxlsx/readxlsx.php",                          
                    method:"POST",              
                    data:{label:label },            
                 success:function(data){            
                         $('#sheetnames').html(data);           
                    }  
            });
          });   

        });     
    }); 
</script>
</head>

<body>
 <br>
 <br>
 <br>
    <div class="container">
        <table>                 
            <thead>                 
                <div class="input-group">                                   
                            <label class="input-group-btn">     
                                <span class="btn btn-primary">      
                                    Browse <input type="file" id="uploadfile" name="uploadfile" style="display: none;" accept="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet, application/vnd.ms-excel">        
                                </span>     
                            </label>        
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" readonly="">        
                </div>                          
            </thead>                
        </table>                    
    </div>
    <div class="input-group" name='sheetnames' id='sheetnames'>

                            </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

The ajax called php file readxlxs.php is as follows:-

```
<?php

    ini_set("xdebug.var_display_max_children", -1);
    ini_set("xdebug.var_display_max_data", -1);
    ini_set("xdebug.var_display_max_depth", -1);    

    ob_start();



    include_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/CommandWks/phpAssets/Classes/PHPExcel.php';

        $exceldata = array();   
    //$inputfilename =   $_POST['label'];
    $inputfilename =  basename($_FILES['fileName']);
    var_dump($inputfilename);
        $inputfiletype = PHPExcel_IOFactory::identify($inputfilename);

        $objReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader($inputfiletype);
        $objPHPExcel = $objReader->load($inputfilename);

        $excelReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReaderForFile($inputfiletype);
        $excelObj = $excelReader->load($inputfiletype);
        $worksheet = $excelObj->getSheet(0);
        $lastRow = $worksheet->getHighestRow();
        var_dump($lastRow);

    ob_end_flush(); 

?>
```

A screenshot of the error displayed is this

[image]

Where is the error? Or is it that PHPExcel cannot be used with ajax?

Comment: You're trying to get the file from **$_FILES['fileName']** and should be **$_FILES['fileName']['tmp_name']** I guess your input file is named **fileName**.

Answer (score 0):

general advice

- you could use browser debug console (F12 if chrome) to see if file actually got upload
- you could var_dump($_FILES) to see actually what server got
- this has nothing to do with begin ajax vs PHPExcel, I think you got it wrong at the basic level of how to handle form data in PHP

and on your question, since your file input is like this

```
<input type="file" id="uploadfile" name="uploadfile"
```

variable name must be

```
$_FILES["uploadfile"]
```

and "name" is just name, for actual file you'll have to use

```
$_FILES["uploadfile"]["tmp_name"]
```

read this for [more info on $_FILES array structure](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.files.php#89674)

> ```
> Array
> (
>     [file1] => Array
>         (
>             [name] => MyFile.txt (comes from the browser, so treat as tainted)
>             [type] => text/plain  (not sure where it gets this from - assume the browser, so treat as tainted)
>             [tmp_name] => /tmp/php/php1h4j1o (could be anywhere on your system, depending on your config settings, but the user has no control, so this isn't tainted)
>             [error] => UPLOAD_ERR_OK  (= 0)
>             [size] => 123   (the size in bytes)
>         )
> )
> ```

Comment: Thanks sir, will check out your advise